# How to load registry hive for all users in a loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

With admin privileges, I need to enumerate all users on a Windows 7+ system (even ones that are logged off). Then I need to load the registry hive for each user and set a key.

NetUserEnum gives me the SID (I guess LsaEnumerateLogonSessions would as well). WTSEnumerateSessions followed by WTSQueryUserToken (to get a token) would be nice but it does not work for users who are not actively logged on.

So, my question, after calling NetUserEnum, how do I use the SID to load the registry for that user? Any recommended way of doing this?

Comment: `NetUserEnum()` can return usernames. Don't those usernames match the subfolders in your `Users` folder? For that matter, you could just enumerate the `Users` subfolders instead and not use `NetUserEnum()` at all. Or even enumerate the `HKEY_USERS` subkeys in the Registry directly.

Comment: If a profile is not loaded, it does not appear in HKEY_USERS, hence the need to RegLoadKey or LoadUserProfile. I don't want to use a password, so LogonUser is out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information about local user profiles is stored in this Registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

It is possible to enumerate it subkeys, where each subkey has a `ProfileImagePath` that points to the folder where `ntuser.dat` is located.

But, directly loading a user profile by `RegLoadKey()` is very bad. First, the profile may already be loaded. Second, it is possible that after you load the profile yourself, the system may also try loading the profile. Note the `RefCount` value. The system uses that value to load the profile if it is not already loaded, incrementing `RefCount`. And `UnloadUserProfile()` decrements `RefCount` and unloads the profile only when it become 0 by calling `RegUnLoadKey()`. So all profile load/unload operations must be synchronized.

There is only one correct way to load a profile - call [`LoadUserProfile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281(v=vs.85).aspx). (internally it performs a RPC call to `profsvc.LoadUserProfileServer` in `svchost.exe -k netsvcs`, where all synchronization is done).

So how do you get the user token for `LoadUserProfile()` ? I guess call [`LogonUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx), which you said you do not want to do (and cannot unless you have the user's password).

But, there does exist another way that works (I tested this), but it is *undocumented*. `LoadUserProfile` used only the user `Sid` from token (query for [`TOKEN_USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379634(v=vs.85).aspx) information with [`TokenUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) iformation class) and then work with

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<Sid>
```

key

It is possible to create a token by calling `ZwCreateToken()` with any given SID, but for this call you need `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE`. This priviledge exists only in the `lsass.exe` process. So a possible solution is:

1. open `lsass.exe` and get its token, or impersonate its thread.
2. enable `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` in the token, after impersonation
3. enumerate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, and for each subkey query its `Sid` value, or (if `Sid` does not exist) convert the subkey name to a SID using `ConvertStringSidToSid()`
4. create a token with that SID
5. and finally call `LoadUserProfile()`

**-------------- EDIT code example by request ----------------------------**

*code used ntdll export (which somebody here very not like) but as is*

1. we need got `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` to create token by yourself in
   future

enum processes in the system, open token for every process, look are `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` exist in token, if yes - duplicate this token and if need enable `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` in it. finally impersonate with duplicated token

```
BOOL g_IsXP;// true if we on winXP, false otherwise
static volatile UCHAR guz;
static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa) };

NTSTATUS ImpersonateIfConformToken(HANDLE hToken)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x200;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptp;
    };

    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryInformationToken(hToken, TokenPrivileges, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            if (ULONG PrivilegeCount = ptp->PrivilegeCount)
            {
                PLUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges = ptp->Privileges;
                do 
                {
                    if (Privileges->Luid.LowPart == SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE && !Privileges->Luid.HighPart)
                    {
                        static SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
                            sizeof sqos, SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING, FALSE
                        };

                        static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES soa = { sizeof(soa), 0, 0, 0, 0, &sqos };

                        if (0 <= (status = ZwDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, &soa, FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hToken)))
                        {
                            if (Privileges->Attributes & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)
                            {
                                status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                static TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = {
                                    1, { { { SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE }, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED } }
                                };

                                status = ZwAdjustPrivilegesToken(hToken, FALSE, &tp, 0, 0, 0);
                            }

                            if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                            {
                                status = ZwSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hToken, sizeof(HANDLE));
                            }

                            ZwClose(hToken);
                        }

                        return status;
                    }
                } while (Privileges++, --PrivilegeCount);
            }

            return STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL);

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS GetCreateTokenPrivilege()
{
    BOOLEAN b;
    RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x10000;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PBYTE pb;
        PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
    };

    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

            ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
            do 
            {
                pb += NextEntryOffset;

                if (pspi->InheritedFromUniqueProcessId && pspi->UniqueProcessId)
                {
                    CLIENT_ID cid = { pspi->UniqueProcessId };

                    NTSTATUS s = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                    HANDLE hProcess, hToken;

                    if (0 <= ZwOpenProcess(&hProcess, g_IsXP ? PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION : PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &zoa, &cid))
                    {
                        if (0 <= ZwOpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
                        {
                            s = ImpersonateIfConformToken(hToken);

                            NtClose(hToken);
                        }

                        NtClose(hProcess);
                    }

                    if (s == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
                    }
                }

            } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

            return status;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}
```

if we have `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_PRIVILEGE` - we can create token !

```
NTSTATUS CreateUserToken(PHANDLE phToken, PSID Sid)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
    NTSTATUS status = ZwOpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryInformationToken(hToken, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &ts.DynamicCharged)))
        {
            ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x200;
            PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

            union {
                PVOID buf;
                PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptp;
            };

            do 
            {
                if (cb < rcb)
                {
                    cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                }

                if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryInformationToken(hToken, TokenPrivileges, buf, cb, &rcb)))
                {
                    TOKEN_USER User = { { Sid } };

                    static TOKEN_SOURCE Source = { {' ','U','s','e','r','3','2', ' '} };

                    static TOKEN_DEFAULT_DACL tdd;// 0 default DACL
                    static TOKEN_GROUPS Groups;// no groups

                    static SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
                        sizeof sqos, SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING
                    };

                    static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { 
                        sizeof oa, 0, 0, 0, 0, &sqos
                    };

                    status = ZwCreateToken(phToken, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &oa, TokenPrimary, 
                        &ts.AuthenticationId, &ts.ExpirationTime, &User, &Groups, ptp, (PTOKEN_OWNER)&Sid,
                        (PTOKEN_PRIMARY_GROUP)&Sid, &tdd, &Source);

                    break;
                }

            } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL);
        }

        ZwClose(hToken);
    }

    return status;
}
```

and finally enumerate and load/unload user profiles

```
void EnumProf()
{
    PROFILEINFO pi = { sizeof(pi), PI_NOUI };
    pi.lpUserName = L"*";

    STATIC_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES(soa, "\\REGISTRY\\MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList");

    HANDLE hKey;
    if (0 <= ZwOpenKey(&hKey, KEY_READ, &soa))
    {
        PVOID stack = alloca(sizeof(WCHAR));

        union
        {
            PVOID buf;
            PKEY_BASIC_INFORMATION pkbi;
            PKEY_VALUE_PARTIAL_INFORMATION pkvpi;
        } u = {};

        DWORD cb = 0, rcb = 64;
        NTSTATUS status;
        ULONG Index = 0;

        do 
        {
            do 
            {
                if (cb < rcb)
                {
                    cb = RtlPointerToOffset(u.buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                }

                if (0 <= (status = ZwEnumerateKey(hKey, Index, KeyBasicInformation, u.buf, cb, &rcb)))
                {
                    *(PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(u.pkbi->Name, u.pkbi->NameLength) = 0;

                    PSID Sid;
                    if (ConvertStringSidToSidW(u.pkbi->Name, &Sid))
                    {
                        HANDLE hToken;

                        if (0 <= CreateUserToken(&hToken, Sid))
                        {
                            if (LoadUserProfile(hToken, &pi))
                            {
                                UnloadUserProfile(hToken, pi.hProfile);
                            }

                            NtClose(hToken);
                        }
                        LocalFree(Sid);
                    }
                }

            } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW);

            Index++;

        } while (0 <= status);

        ZwClose(hKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: A C++ version of this would be nice? https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2012/01/13/update-a-registry-key-for-all-users-on-a-system/

Comment: I like the sounds of Option 2, query for Token_user. Can you elaborate more on that? What are the steps?

Comment: @pcunite - ok . i paste full working code, but not sure that you can use it as is or modify for self